# FullCalendar.js External Element Dragging Color and Data

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar-5

I have a FullCalendar.js (version 5+) ([www.FullCalendar.io](http://www.FullCalendar.io)) based application where I am trying to drag External Elements onto a Calendar. The Events on the Calendar contain some Events which are displayed using `EventContent` based 'injection'code. What I want to do is that when an External Element is dragged to the Calendar then not only it retains the Element's color but also doesn't show injected code. You can see my progress so far in this Pen: https://codepen.io/IrfanClemson/pen/YzWRxLN

Please see this screen cap to see the issue:

[image]

So when 'My Event 1' is dragged then only 'My Event 1' should show with its yellow color and shouldn't show the blue injected code such as 'ADDRESS HERE'.

Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out. Some of the solution is reflected in the modified `EventContent` property of Pen at: https://codepen.io/IrfanClemson/pen/YzWRxLN

Basically, `EventContent` was determining the content of both dragged and dynamically added Events. So if dragging then catch that in an if/else statement, as can be seen in the Pen linked above.

Sorry, can't share all the code--too much but I think this might help someone!